# Issue when using distributive conditional types combined with generic method

Tags: typescript, generics, types, conditional-statements, distributive

I've been trying to make a generic function which receives and object T and receives a string property name of that object T.

I used https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html as an example (section: Distributive conditional types)

I've come up with a solution that works without generics, but when I change the explicit types to a generic type typescript won't compile.

This is the non-generic version:

```js
export type TypedPropertyNames<T, P> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends P ? K : never }[keyof T];
export type StringPropertyNames<T> = TypedPropertyNames<T, string>;

interface Test {
  test: string;
}
 
function non_generic(form: Test, field: StringPropertyNames<Test>): string {
  return form[field];
}
```

This works.

Now when I change the Test interface into a generic argument it won't compile anymore.

```js
export type TypedPropertyNames<T, P> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends P ? K : never }[keyof T];
export type StringPropertyNames<T> = TypedPropertyNames<T, string>;

function generic<T>(form: T, field: StringPropertyNames<T>): string {
  return form[field]; // This won't compile
}
```

Is this expected behaviour? Or is this a typescript bug?
Can anyone point me in the direction of making the generic version work (without any hacks)

## Update 1:

Compilation error:

```
Type 'T[{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never; }[keyof T]]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20type%20TypedPropertyNames%3CT%2C%20P%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BK%5D%20extends%20P%20%3F%20K%20%3A%20never%20%7D%5Bkeyof%20T%5D%3B%0D%0Aexport%20type%20StringPropertyNames%3CT%3E%20%3D%20TypedPropertyNames%3CT%2C%20string%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20generic%3CT%3E(form%3A%20T%2C%20field%3A%20StringPropertyNames%3CT%3E)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20form%5Bfield%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20This%20won%27t%20compile%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Can you share the compilation error?

Comment: I updated the question and also added a link to the typescript playground

Comment: Conditional types with unresolved parameters can't be resolved so can't be reasoned about ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler generally cannot determine assignability of unresolved conditional types (that is, conditional types which cannot be eagerly evaluated because at least one of the `T` or `U` in `T extends U ? V : W` is not yet fully specified).

This is more of a design limitation than a bug (see [Microsoft/TypeScript#30728](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30728)); the compiler is not going to be as smart as a human being (note to self: come back here when the machine uprising happens and edit this) so we shouldn't expect it to just "notice" that `T[TypedPropertyName<T,P>] extends P` should always be true.  We could write a particular heuristic algorithm to detect the situation and perform the desired reduction, but it would have to be able to run *very quickly* so that it doesn't degrade compile times for the 99% of the time when it wouldn't be useful.

> Can anyone point me in the direction of making the generic version work (without any hacks)

That really depends on what you consider a hack.  The absolute simplest thing to do is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), which is explicitly intended for times when you know something is type safe but the compiler isn't able to figure it out:

```
function generic<T>(form: T, field: StringPropertyNames<T>): string {
  return form[field] as any as string;  // I'm smarter than the compiler 
}
```

Or you could try to lead the compiler through the steps necessary to understand that what you're doing is safe.  In particular, the compiler *does* understand that `Record<K, V>[K]` is assignable to `V` (where `Record<K, V>` is defined in [the standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.4.5/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1449-L1454) as a mapped type whose keys are in `K` and whose values are in `V`).  You can therefore constrain the type `T` like this:

```
function generic<T extends Record<StringPropertyNames<T>, string>>(
  form: T,
  field: StringPropertyNames<T>
): string {
  return form[field]; // okay
}
```

Now the compiler is happy.  And the constraint `T extends Record<StringPropertyNames<T>, string>` isn't really a constraint at all, since any object type will conform to it (e.g., `{a: string, b: number}` extends `Record<'a', string>`).  So you should be able to use it anywhere you use the original definition (for concrete types `T` anyway):

```
interface Foo {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: boolean;
  d: "d";
}
declare const foo: Foo;
generic(foo, "a"); // okay
generic(foo, "d"); // okay
```

Are those hacks? ‍♂️ Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: I went with the `Record` method because I felt this one is the least hacky. The only downside is that it requires my object to have at least one property of the type `string`, but that's sufficient for my use case.

Comment: Does it actually require that? `{a: number}` extends `Record<never, string>`, so the compiler shouldn't complain if the `form` parameter has no known string properties.  Of course, the `field` parameter will have to be `never`, which is fairly useless, but it's the same amount useless as your original definition.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I do not know what the issue is. You might try filing a issue on their GH. However, I do know that the following does work without explicitly specifying the return type:

```js
function generic<T>(form: T, field: StringPropertyNames<T>) {
  return form[field];
}
```

and it even correctly types the return value as a string:

```js
const test = {
  a: "b",
  c: 1,
  "other": "blah"
}
generic(test, "a").charAt(0) //passes - "b"
generic(test, "a") * 5 // fails - function result is not a number
generic(test, "c") //fails - "c" is not assignable to "a" | "other"
```

I would additionally recommend this addition to make sure the first argument must be an object:

```js
function generic<T extends object>(form: T, field: StringPropertyNames<T>) {
  return form[field];
}
```

Comment: I did open an issue on github (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31275)